# file name matching with wildcard

Tags: c++, c, windows, filesystems

I need to implement something like my own file system. One operation would be the FindFirstFile. I need to check, if the caller passed something like *.*, sample*.cpp or so. My "file system" implementation provides the list of "files names" as a array of char*.

Is there any Windows function or any source code that implements this file name matching?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are quite a few such functions around. Here's a [directory](http://xoomer.virgilio.it/acantato/dev/wildcard/wildmatch.html) of various implementations, sorted into recursive and non-recursive, etc.

In case you don't like the licensing there (or have trouble with the link, etc.) here's one possible implementation of a matching algorithm that at least closely approximates what Windows uses:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>

bool match(char const *needle, char const *haystack) {
    for (; *needle != '\0'; ++needle) {
        switch (*needle) {
        case '?': 
            if (*haystack == '\0')
                return false;
            ++haystack;
            break;
        case '*': {
            if (needle[1] == '\0')
                return true;
            size_t max = strlen(haystack);
            for (size_t i = 0; i < max; i++)
                if (match(needle + 1, haystack + i))
                    return true;
            return false;
        }
        default:
            if (*haystack != *needle)
                return false;
            ++haystack;
        }
    }
    return *haystack == '\0';
}

#ifdef TEST
#define CATCH_CONFIG_MAIN

#include "catch.hpp"

TEST_CASE("Matching", "[match]") {
    REQUIRE(match("a", "a") == true);
    REQUIRE(match("a", "b") == false);
    REQUIRE(match("a*", "a") == true);
    REQUIRE(match("a?", "a") == false);
    REQUIRE(match("a?", "ab") == true);
    REQUIRE(match("a*b", "ab") == true);
    REQUIRE(match("a*b", "acb") == true);
    REQUIRE(match("a*b", "abc") == false);
    REQUIRE(match("*a*??????a?????????a???????????????", 
        "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa") == true);
}

#endif
```

Since there was a discussion of complexity of some of the other answers, I'll note that I believe this has O(NM) complexity and O(M) storage use (where N is the size of the target string, and M is the size of the pattern).

With @masterxilo's test pair:

```
"*a*??????*a*?????????a???????????????", "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"
```

...this finds a match in approximately 3 microseconds on my machine. That *is* a lot slower than a typical pattern--most of my other tests run in about 300 nanoseconds or so on this particular machine.

At the same time, @masterxilo's code takes approximately 11 microseconds to run on the same machine, so this is still around 3 to 4 times faster (not to mention being somewhat smaller and simpler).

Comment: not only bizaree, but slightly braindead. E.g., if I work for LibreOffice, and LibreOffice is used by such an army, I may not use the code ...

Comment: @phresnel: That only applies to *his* code. A fair amount of what's there isn't his (e.g., a couple have no restrictions at all).

Comment: Though he also mentions he modified a few of them. Attorney needed.

Comment: maybe it's just for me it isn't working, but still cannot access

Comment: I think there's a smal bug in your code: `if (needle[1] == '\0' || max == 0) return true;` The `|| max == 0` part should IMHO be left off, because then a haystack "test.txt" would match a needle "test.txt*suffix".

Comment: @MarcoFreudenberger: Thanks--I believe I've corrected that (and updated the code to include some test cases).

Answer (score 21):

For wildcard name matching using '*' and '?' try this (if you want to avoid boost, use std::tr1::regex):

```
#include <boost/regex.hpp>
#include <boost/algorithm/string/replace.hpp>

using std::string;

bool MatchTextWithWildcards(const string &text, string wildcardPattern, bool caseSensitive /*= true*/)
{
    // Escape all regex special chars
    EscapeRegex(wildcardPattern);

    // Convert chars '*?' back to their regex equivalents
    boost::replace_all(wildcardPattern, "\\?", ".");
    boost::replace_all(wildcardPattern, "\\*", ".*");

    boost::regex pattern(wildcardPattern, caseSensitive ? regex::normal : regex::icase);

    return regex_match(text, pattern);
}

void EscapeRegex(string &regex)
{
    boost::replace_all(regex, "\\", "\\\\");
    boost::replace_all(regex, "^", "\\^");
    boost::replace_all(regex, ".", "\\.");
    boost::replace_all(regex, "$", "\\$");
    boost::replace_all(regex, "|", "\\|");
    boost::replace_all(regex, "(", "\\(");
    boost::replace_all(regex, ")", "\\)");
    boost::replace_all(regex, "{", "\\{");
    boost::replace_all(regex, "{", "\\}");
    boost::replace_all(regex, "[", "\\[");
    boost::replace_all(regex, "]", "\\]");
    boost::replace_all(regex, "*", "\\*");
    boost::replace_all(regex, "+", "\\+");
    boost::replace_all(regex, "?", "\\?");
    boost::replace_all(regex, "/", "\\/");
}
```

Comment: You almost got this right. You don't need begin and end symbols with regex_match(). Also you need to escape { and }. I've submitted an edit so these changes will probably be integrated into your answer.

Comment: @David: I need the begin/end symbols because I want the complete filename to match from begin to end. I don't want to match if only parts of the filename match. This is the behaviour one is used to from the commandline.

Comment: regex_match will only match the whole input sequence, thus ^ and $ are redundant. Perhaps you're thinking of regex_search?

Comment: @David You are right. I removed the redundant code. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Where is the mentioned escape for `{`and `}`? I tested the code with `std::regex` and there the escaping is needed!

Answer (score 12):

Have a look at the POSIX functions `fnmatch`, `glob`, and `wordexp`.

Answer (score 5):

#### Here's my attempt at this.

It's "C++", but I've deliberately kept it almost completely C-compatible.
All you need to do in order to convert it to C is to remove the `template` section and change `Pattern` and `Text` to something like `char const *`.

```
// TEST THIS before use! I've only done limited testing.

#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

template<class Pattern, class Text>
bool wildcard(
    Pattern const pat_begin, Pattern const pat_end,
    Text text_begin, Text const text_end)
{
    ptrdiff_t const pat_size = pat_end - pat_begin;
    ptrdiff_t stackbuf[64];
    size_t c = sizeof(stackbuf) / sizeof(*stackbuf);
    ptrdiff_t *p = stackbuf;
    size_t n = 0;
    p[n++] = 0;
    while (n > 0 && text_begin != text_end)
    {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            if (p[i] == pat_size)
            {
                p[i--] = p[--n];
                continue;
            }
            switch (*(pat_begin + p[i]))
            {
            case '?': ++p[i]; break;
            case '*':
                ptrdiff_t off;
                off = p[i];
                while (off < pat_size &&
                    *(pat_begin + off) == '*')
                { ++off; }
                if (n == c)
                {
                    ptrdiff_t const *const old = p;
                    c *= 2;
                    if (c == 0) { ++c; }
                    size_t const size = c * sizeof(*p);
                    p = (ptrdiff_t *)realloc(
                        old == stackbuf ? NULL : p,
                        size);
                    if (old == stackbuf)
                    { memcpy(p, old, n * sizeof(*old)); }
                }
                p[n++] = off;
                break;
            default:
                if (*(pat_begin + p[i]) == *text_begin)
                { ++p[i]; }
                else { p[i--] = p[--n]; }
                break;
            }
        }
        ++text_begin;
    }
    bool success = false;
    if (text_begin == text_end)
    {
        while (!success && n > 0)
        {
            --n;
            while (p[n] != pat_size &&
                *(pat_begin + p[n]) == '*')
            { ++p[n]; }
            if (p[n] == pat_size)
            { success = true; }
        }
    }
    if (p != stackbuf) { free(p); }
    return success;
}

bool wildcard(char const *const pattern, char const *const text)
{
    return wildcard(
        pattern,
        pattern + (pattern ? strlen(pattern) : 0),
        text,
        text + (text ? strlen(text) : 0));
}

bool wildcard(wchar_t const *const pattern, wchar_t const *const text)
{
    return wildcard(
        pattern,
        pattern + (pattern ? wcslen(pattern) : 0),
        text,
        text + (text ? wcslen(text) : 0));
}
```

Of course, feel free to use the code in any way you want. :)

Comment: This has worst case exponential running time.

Comment: @masterxilo: Can you show me an example for which that is true?

Answer (score 3):

The solution Mehrdad provided has exponential running time because it uses backtracking. It takes it like a second to figure out that `"*a*??????*a*?????????a???????????????", "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"` is a match. Also there's no way to match a string with '*' or '?' in it.

Here's an O(nm) implementation I came up with which has O(n) memory usage, where n is the length of the expression, m the length of the string. It also supports escaping ?, * and \.

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

/** 
 * Wildcard matching.
 * See for example
 * http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/find_c_search_wildcard.mspx?mfr=true
 *
 *  * matches any amount of any characters, 
 *  ? matches any single character.
 *  c matches c.
 *  No escaping of * and ? implemented (these are not allowed in windows filenames anyways).
 *
 * Backtracking O(2^n) implementation.
 *
 * from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3300419/file-name-matching-with-wildcard 
 * http://stackoverflow.com/a/12231681/524504
 */
template<class Pattern, class Text>
bool wildcard(
        Pattern const pat_begin,
        Pattern const pat_end,
        Text text_begin, 
        Text const text_end)
{
    ptrdiff_t const pat_size = pat_end - pat_begin;

    /* initial pattern position stack (offsets into the pattern string) and its size c */
    ptrdiff_t stackbuf[64];
    size_t c                     = sizeof(stackbuf) / sizeof(*stackbuf);
    /* Stack base. Can be realloc'ed to some new memory location if we need more */
    ptrdiff_t *p                 = stackbuf;

    /* pointer to the location in the stack */
    size_t n                     = 0;
    p[n++]                       = 0; /* position 0 in the stack not used */

    /* text_begin updated to skip everything successfully consumed  */
    while (n > 0 && text_begin != text_end) 
    {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) 
        {
            /* if we're at the end of the pattern, but not at the end of the 
             * string, we might have done something wrong.
             */
            if (p[i] == pat_size) 
            {
                p[i--] = p[--n];
                continue;
            }
            /* current pattern character */
            switch (*(pat_begin + p[i]))
            {
                case '?': ++p[i]; break; /* simply advance pattern pointer */
                case '*':
                          ptrdiff_t off;
                          off = p[i];
                          while (off < pat_size &&
                                  *(pat_begin + off) == '*')
                          { ++off; }
                          /* if the stack is full, reallocate */
                          if (n == c)
                          {
                              ptrdiff_t const *const old = p;
                              c *= 2;
                              /* assert positive size
                               * stack size never reduced anyways?
                               */
                              if (c == 0) { ++c; }
                              size_t const size = c * sizeof(*p);
                              /* cannot use realloc to copy original stack 
                               * (ptr in realloc must be 
                               * "Pointer to a memory block previously 
                               * allocated with malloc, calloc or realloc."
                               * must do manually
                               */
                              p = (ptrdiff_t *)realloc(
                                       old == stackbuf ? NULL : p,
                                      size);
                              if (old == stackbuf)
                              { memcpy(p, old, n * sizeof(*old)); }
                          }
                          /* store offset */
                          p[n++] = off;
                          break;
                default: /* a normal character in the pattern */
                          /* must be matched exactly */
                          if (*(pat_begin + p[i]) == *text_begin)
                          { ++p[i]; } /* advance pattern pointer */
                          else /* if not, backtrack */
                          { p[i--] = p[--n]; }
                          break;
            }
        }
        ++text_begin;
    }

    bool success = false;
    if (text_begin == text_end)
    {
        while (!success && n > 0)
        {
            --n;
            while (p[n] != pat_size &&
                    *(pat_begin + p[n]) == '*')
            { ++p[n]; }
            if (p[n] == pat_size)
            { success = true; }
        }
    }

    /* need to free stack if it was reallocated */
    if (p != stackbuf) { free(p); }
    return success;
}

bool wildcard(char const *const pattern, char const *const text)
{
    return wildcard(
            pattern,
            pattern + (pattern ? strlen(pattern) : 0),
            text,
            text + (text ? strlen(text) : 0));
}

bool wildcard(wchar_t const *const pattern, wchar_t const *const text)
{
    return wildcard(
            pattern,
            pattern + (pattern ? wcslen(pattern) : 0),
            text,
            text + (text ? wcslen(text) : 0));
}

/**
 * Virtual Machine Style Regular Expression parsing/NFA emulation
 * used for wildcard matching. O(nm) algorithm.
 *
 * See http://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/ for more on efficient RegEx parsing.
 *
 * Copyright (c) March 29, 2013 Paul Frischknecht
 * Can be distributed under the MIT licence, see bottom of file.
 */

//#define wildcard_fast_DEBUG /* define to make the alogorithm printf what its doing */

/**
 * Instructions are:
 *
 * star
 *   This launches a new thread at the current position and continues with the 
 *   current thread at the next position accepting any character.
 * char c
 *   Accepts exactly the character c
 * anychar
 *   Accepts any character.
 * end 
 *   Accepts the end of the input string.
 */
enum InstructionType {
    End     = 0,
    Star    = 1,
    Char    = 2,
    AnyChar = 3
};

struct Instruction {
    InstructionType i;
    int c;       /* the caracter this instruction matches - undefined for non Char */
    int threads; /* threads active in the given instruction */
    /*
     * storing this here allows us to find out wether there is a thread
     * active at a given instruction in O(1)
     */
};

/** 
 * Wildcard (file path) matching.
 * See for example 
 * http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/find_c_search_wildcard.mspx?mfr=true
 *
 *  * matches any amount of any characters, 
 *  ? matches any single character.
 *  c matches c.
 *
 * Escaping of '*', '?' and '\' via '\*', '\?' and '\\' implemented. 
 * All other bytes are recognized directly as is. 
 * The string may not end in a single (uneven amount of) '\'.
 *
 * If text_end is 0, the text is assumed to be 0 terminated.
 * Same for pattern_end. The end is exclusive.
 *
 * @return A pointer to the character after the last character matched.
 *
 * Virtual machine O(nm) implementation, see http://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/regexp2.html
 *
 * TODO Factor out the precompilation step to speed up matching multiple strings
 * against the same expression.
 */
template<class Pattern, class Text>
Text wildcard_fast(
        Pattern const pat_begin,
        Pattern const pat_end,
        Text const text_begin, 
        Text const text_end)
{
    /* 
     * give some reasonable default program size so we don't have to call
     * malloc in most cases 
     */
    #define DEFAULTonstack_program_SIZE 256
    Instruction onstack_program[DEFAULTonstack_program_SIZE];
    /* this stores the current run and next run thread list, alternating */
    /* there are as most as many threads as instructions */
    Instruction* onstack_threads[DEFAULTonstack_program_SIZE*2]; 

    Instruction** threads      = onstack_threads;
    Instruction*  program      = onstack_program;
    int           program_size = sizeof(onstack_program)/sizeof(*program);

    Instruction* program_last_instruction = program + program_size - 1;

    /* program and pattern pointers */
    Instruction* pp   = program;
    Pattern      patp = pat_begin;

    /* compile */

    while ((pat_end == 0 && *patp != 0) || (pat_end != 0 && patp != pat_end)) {

        /* need more space */
        if (pp == program_last_instruction) {

            Instruction*  old_program = program;
            Instruction** old_threads = threads;
            int old_program_size      = program_size;

            program_size *= 2;

            program = (Instruction*) malloc(program_size*sizeof(*program));
            threads = (Instruction**)malloc(program_size*sizeof(*threads)*2);

            memcpy(program, old_program, old_program_size*sizeof(*program));

            if (old_program != onstack_program) {
                free(old_program); free(old_threads);
            }

            program_last_instruction = program + program_size - 1;
            pp = pp - old_program + program;
        }

        /* parse pattern */
        switch (*patp) {
            case '*': 
                pp->i = Star; 
                /* Optimize multiple stars away */
                while ((pat_end == 0 || patp+1 != pat_end) && *(patp+1) == '*')  
                    patp++; 
                break;

            case '?':
                pp->i = AnyChar; 
                break;

            case '\\': 
                pp->i = Char; 
                pp->c = *(++patp); /* assumes string does not end in \ */
                break;

            default: 
                pp->i = Char; 
                pp->c = *patp; 
                break;
        }

        pp->threads = 0;

        pp++;
        patp++;
    }

    /* add the End instruction at the end */
    program_last_instruction = pp;
    pp->i                    = End;
    pp->threads              = 0;

    /* run */
    Text sp = text_begin; /* input string pointer */
    int n = 1, c = 0; /* next and current index */
    int threadcount[2];

    /* initialize */
    threadcount[c] = 1;
    threads[0] = program;
    threads[0]->threads++;

    /* run over text */
    while ((text_end == 0 && *sp != 0) || (text_end != 0 && sp != text_end)) {
        /* unless recreated, all threads will die */
        threadcount[n] = 0;

        /* run over threads */
        for (int i = 0; i < threadcount[c]; i++) {

            Instruction* inst = threads[2*i+c];
            switch (inst->i) {
                case End: 
                    /* we may not reach end early */ 
                    /* kill this thread without recrating it */
                    inst->threads--; 
                    continue; /* with for loop */

                case Char: 
                    if (*sp != inst->c) {
                        /* if the character is not matched, kill this thread */
                        inst->threads--;
                        continue;
                    }
                    break;

                case Star: 
                    /* spawn off additional thread at current location */

                    if (inst->threads == 1) { 
                        /* only if there's noone active there yet */
                        threads[2*(threadcount[n]++)+n] = inst;
                        inst->threads++;
                    }
                    break;
            }
            /* 
             * common actions: increase program counter for current thread,
             * decrese amount of threads in last (current) instruction.
             */
            inst->threads--;
            inst++;
            inst->threads++;

            /* respawn at new location in next iteration */
            threads[2*(threadcount[n]++)+n] = inst;

            if (inst->i == Star && (inst+1)->threads == 0) { 
                /* 
                 * already follow no-match option to give us 
                 * more stuff to do 
                 */
                threads[2*(threadcount[n]++)+n] = inst+1;
                (inst+1)->threads++;
            }

#ifdef wildcard_fast_DEBUG
              for (int i = 0 ; i < threadcount[n]; i++) {
                printf("thread %d at %d.\n", i, threads[2*i+n]-program);
            }
#endif

        }

#ifdef wildcard_fast_DEBUG
        const char *ns[] = {
            "end",
            "star",
            "char",
            "anychar",
        };
        for (Instruction* p = program; p->i; p++) {
            printf("%d. %s %c (%d threads)\n", p-program, ns[p->i], p->i == Char ? p->c : ' ', p->threads);
        }
#endif

        /* swap next and current and advance */
        n = c;
        c = !c;
        sp++;
    }

    /* 
     * if there is no thread active in the End instruction when the 
     * end of the input was reached, this was no match
     */
    if (program_last_instruction->threads == 0) sp = 0; 

    if (program != onstack_program) {
        /* only need to free if we used malloc */
        free(program); free(threads);
    }

    return sp;
}

char const* wildcard_fast(
        char const *const pattern, 
        char const *const text) 
{
    return wildcard_fast(
            pattern,
            (const char*)0,
            text,
            (const char*)0);
}

wchar_t const* wildcard_fast(
        wchar_t const *const pattern,
        wchar_t const *const text) 
{
    return wildcard_fast(
            pattern,
            (const wchar_t*)0,
            text,
            (const wchar_t*)0);
}


/* tests */
#ifndef INCLUDE_IMPLEMENTATION
/* 
 * I just include this file in my projects and define this.
 * That works well for simple algorithms like this
 */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main() {
    struct {
        char* p;
        char* t;
        bool expected_result;
    } test[] = {
        {
            "",
            "",
            true
        },
        {
            "a",
            "",
            false
        },
        {
            "",
            "a",
            false
        },
        {
            "a",
            "a",
            true
        },        
        {
            "****.txt", 
            "hello.txt",
            true
        },
        {
            "*.txt", 
            "hello.tzt",
            false
        },
        {
            "*.t?t*", 
            "hello.tzt",
            true
        },
        {
            "*.*", 
            "hi.there",
            true
        },
        /* the wildcard implementation will fail this as it doesn't understand escaping */
        {
            "\\*who\\?\\?.*\\\\", 
            "*who??.there\\",
            true
        },        
        /* these take extraordinaryly long on the O(2^n) implementation */
        {
            "**a*************************??????***a************************?????????a???????????????", 
            "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa",
            true
        },
        /* runs a bit better if we omit the extra *'s. The fast implementation already optimizes these away. */
        {
            "*a*??????*a*?????????a???????????????", 
            "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa",
            true
        },
        {0,0} /* marks end of tests */
    };

    int t0 = clock();
    const char* result;
    const char* r[] = {"no match", "match"};

    for (int i = 0; test[i].p; i++) {
        printf("=== Test %d: Matching '%s' against '%s'...===\n", i, test[i].t, test[i].p);

        /* wildcard_fast */
        t0 = clock();
        result = wildcard_fast(test[i].p, test[i].t);

        printf("  wildcard_fast (took %d ms):\n", clock()-t0);
        if (!!result != test[i].expected_result)
            printf("    Test failed (reported %s instead of expected %s).\n",
                    r[!!result], r[test[i].expected_result]);
        else if (result) {
            printf("    %s\n", test[i].t);
            printf("    %*.c\n", result-test[i].t+1, '^');
        }
        else
            printf("    No match.\n");

        /* wildcard */
        t0 = clock();
        result = (const char*)
            wildcard(test[i].p, test[i].t);

        printf("  wildcard (took %d ms):\n", clock()-t0);
        if (!!result != test[i].expected_result)
            printf("    Test failed (reported %s instead of expected %s).\n",
                    r[!!result], r[test[i].expected_result]);
        else if (result) printf("    Match.\n");
        else printf("    No match.\n");

        printf("\n");
    }
}
#endif

/*
 * Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person
 * obtaining a copy of this software and associated
 * documentation files (the "Software"), to deal in the
 * Software without restriction, including without limitation
 * the rights to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute,
 * sublicense, and/or sell copies of the Software, and to
 * permit persons to whom the Software is furnished to do so,
 * subject to the following conditions:
 * 
 * The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall
 * be included in all copies or substantial portions of the
 * Software.
 * 
 * THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY
 * KIND, EXPRESS OR IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE
 * WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY, FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR
 * PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT.  IN NO EVENT SHALL THE AUTHORS
 * OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR
 * OTHER LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR
 * OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM, OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE
 * SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN THE SOFTWARE.
 */
```

This uses a virtual machine approach. See http://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/ for more on efficitent regular expression parsing.

Comment: *"The solution Mehrdad provided has exponential running time"*... no, it has linear running time. When people talk about regex running time, they are talking about the size of the input string, not the size of the pattern. Both of our examples are linear in the size of the input string; I think yours uses potentially exponential memory in the size of the pattern, and mine uses potentially exponential time in the size of the pattern. You can turn the NFA into a DFA, which is often a good tradeoff, but something which you should mention if you're taking into account the pattern size as you are.

Comment: Speaking of space complexity, I'm pretty sure that your implementation does **not** have "O(n)" memory usage. How could the space usage possibly be independent of the pattern complexity?!

Comment: Just to be clear, `n` is the pattern length, `m` the input string length. The memory usage *is* only dependant of the pattern size `n`, no matter what the pattern is. The memory usage grows linearly in the size of the pattern - it just has to compile the pattern, where one character (1 byte) transforms into exactly one instruction (12 byte). I allocate no additional memory for the input string. I think the backtracking search is worst case exponential in the input string size times the pattern size, because it could make the wrong guess at every pattern character for every input character.

Comment: *"The memory usage is only dependant of the pattern size n, no matter what the pattern is."*... huh? Doesn't the number of threads you spawn depend on the input size? Doesn't every thread consume memory?

Comment: No, there is at most one thread at every instruction. The loop then just goes oever all threads for every character in the input, thus O nm. The article I linked to describes this approach in more detail, it's worth the read.

Comment: Hmm, I'm having trouble understanding how the algorithm in that paper differs in time complexity from what I'm doing. In fact, it seems like both your algorithm and mine are running an NFA. In both cases, we keep track of the current position in the pattern, which has only n possibilities. Can you tell me what you think the time complexity of my code is, and what part of it is exponential?

Comment: Algorithm does not detect match for "\*E450\*" and "E450" strings.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a dependency free portable C++ version:

```
#include <string>

#include <string.h>

bool wild_match(const std::string& str, const std::string& pat) {
  std::string::const_iterator str_it = str.begin();
  for (std::string::const_iterator pat_it = pat.begin(); pat_it != pat.end();
       ++pat_it) {
    switch (*pat_it) {
      case '?':
        if (str_it == str.end()) {
          return false;
        }

        ++str_it;
        break;
      case '*': {
        if (pat_it + 1 == pat.end()) {
          return true;
        }

        const size_t max = strlen(&*str_it);
        for (size_t i = 0; i < max; ++i) {
          if (wild_match(&*(pat_it + 1), &*(str_it + i))) {
            return true;
          }
        }

        return false;
      }
      default:
        if (*str_it != *pat_it) {
          return false;
        }

        ++str_it;
    }
  }

  return str_it == str.end();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[PathMatchSpec](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773727%28VS.85%29.aspx). Though it suffers from the `MAX_PATH` limitation (i.e. can accept no more than 260 characters). You may be better off implementing your own matcher; it's not a lot of code.

Comment: Most maintainable solution ;-)

Answer (score 2):

This is pretty much the same as @nabulke's answer, using C++11 instead of Boost (so be sure to upvote that one too if you like this answer):

```
#include <regex>
#include <string>

std::regex wildcardToRegex(const std::string& wildcard, bool caseSensitive = true)
{
    // Note It is possible to automate checking if filesystem is case sensitive or not (e.g. by performing a test first time this function is ran)
    std::string regexString{ wildcard };
    // Escape all regex special chars:
    regexString = std::regex_replace(regexString, std::regex("\\\\"), "\\\\");
    regexString = std::regex_replace(regexString, std::regex("\\^"), "\\^");
    regexString = std::regex_replace(regexString, std::regex("\\."), "\\.");
    regexString = std::regex_replace(regexString, std::regex("\\$"), "\\$");
    regexString = std::regex_replace(regexString, std::regex("\\|"), "\\|");
    regexString = std::regex_replace(regexString, std::regex("\\("), "\\(");
    regexString = std::regex_replace(regexString, std::regex("\\)"), "\\)");
    regexString = std::regex_replace(regexString, std::regex("\\{"), "\\{");
    regexString = std::regex_replace(regexString, std::regex("\\{"), "\\}");
    regexString = std::regex_replace(regexString, std::regex("\\["), "\\[");
    regexString = std::regex_replace(regexString, std::regex("\\]"), "\\]");
    regexString = std::regex_replace(regexString, std::regex("\\+"), "\\+");
    regexString = std::regex_replace(regexString, std::regex("\\/"), "\\/");
    // Convert wildcard specific chars '*?' to their regex equivalents:
    regexString = std::regex_replace(regexString, std::regex("\\?"), ".");
    regexString = std::regex_replace(regexString, std::regex("\\*"), ".*");

    return std::regex(regexString, caseSensitive ? std::regex_constants::ECMAScript : std::regex_constants::icase);
}

bool wildmatch(const std::string& input, const std::string& wildcard)
{
    auto rgx = wildcardToRegex(wildcard);
    return std::regex_match(input, rgx);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you can try my wildcard matching library: [Wildest card](https://github.com/QtRoS/wildest-card)

It is:

- Based on NFA
- Written in C in single header file
- Has no dependencies
- Has no recursion
- Has no dynamic allocations
- Has O(MN) complexity
- Requires O(logM) memory

Example:

```
#include "wildcard.h"
...
bool answer = wildcard("*.cpp", "file.cpp");
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an efficient one that does a single traverse of the string, and skips comparisons where they're not needed (the last character in pattern happens to be a '*' or if a character before a '*' doesn't have the same index match). It also doesn't copy any strings by making use of pointers and doesn't waste any CPU cycles on getting the string length with strlen(), sizeof(), .length(), or .size()

```
#include <stdio.h>

_Bool wildcard_strcmp(char *line, char *pattern)
{
    _Bool wildcard = 0;
    char *placeholder;

    do
    {
        if ((*pattern == *line) || (*pattern == '?'))
        {
            line++;
            pattern++;
        }
        else if (*pattern == '*')
        {
            if (*(++pattern) == '\0')
                return 1;
            else
            {
                placeholder = pattern;
                wildcard = 1;
            }
        }
        else if (wildcard)
        {
            if (pattern == placeholder)
                line++;
            else
                pattern = placeholder;
        } 
        else
            return 0;
    } while (*line);

    if (*pattern == '\0')
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}

int main()
{
    char string[200] = "foobarfoobar";
    char pattern[200] = "fo?*barfoo*";

    if (wildcard_strcmp(string, pattern))
        printf("Match\n");
    else
        printf("No Match\n");

    return 0;
}
```