# Simple wildcard search algorithm in C++

Tags: c++, string, search, wildcard

I have an assignment in which I have to create a search pattern including wildcard character '?'. We haven't covered anything further than loops and properties of string libraries yet, so my teacher doesn't want me to use arrays or anything we haven't covered.

My problem is to create an algorithm for the special character '?'. Do you have any idea how can I integrate it into my program without using more advanced tricks? Everything I tried is either completely wrong or has some mistakes in it.

Program should request an input from the user for the source string and then, ask for another input for search string which can include '?' in it. For example:

Source string: glorious
Search string: ?r?o

The matched string was found at index: 2
The matched string is: orio

Comment: To clarify: does `?` mean "any one character" or "zero or one character"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the function I came up with. Finally I found a way using limited knowledge of mine. It works, but probably performance is really bad.

Thanks for your all help, they inspired me even though I can't directly use them because of advanced-for me- techniques.

```
void wildcard(string source, string search)
{
    unsigned int j = 0, i = 0, z = 0;
    string s1 = "", search2 = search;
    //Starting with a null string and adding found parts to it

    /*************************IF IT STARTS WITH QUESTION MARK*************************/

    if(search.find('?') == 0)
    {
        for(; search.at(z) == '?'; z++)
            //loop make search string start without question marks.
        {
            search2 = search.substr(z + 1, search.length());
        }

        for(; j <= source.length()-search2.length(); ++j)
            //application of Brute Force Search Algoritm for this case.
        {
            while(i < search2.length() && (source.at(z+i+j) == search2.at(i) || search2.at(i) == '?'))
            {
                s1 = s1 + source.at(z+j+i);
                i++;
            }
        }

        if(s1.length() == search2.length())
            //showing results for this case.
        {
            cout << "The matched string was found at index: " << source.find(s1) - z << endl;
            cout << "The matched string is: " << source.substr((source.find(s1)-z), search.length()) << endl << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "The search string could not found in the source string." << endl << endl;
        }
    }

    /********************IF IT DOES NOT START WITH QUESTION MARK**********************/

    else
        //If it doesnot start with ?, use normal test.
    {
        for(; j <= source.length()-search.length(); ++j)
            //application of Brute Force Search Algoritm for this case.
        {
            while(i < search.length() && (source.at(i+j) == search.at(i) || search.at(i) == '?'))
            {
                s1 = s1 + source.at(j+i);
                i++;
            }
        }

        if(s1.length() == search.length())
            //results
        {
            cout << "The matched string was found at index: " << source.find(s1) << endl;
            cout << "The matched string is: " << s1 << endl << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "The search string could not found in the source string." << endl << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I felt bad for only *hinting* on backtracking and recursion in a comment. Here's an explanation:

#### Strategy:

Focus on the tokens *between* wilcards (the wildcards are not what should be matched).

- extract first token from pattern
- exit with success for no (more) tokens
- for each token match in input

  - match the remainder of the pattern against the remainder of the input
  - if no successful submatch, fail, otherwise done

There is recursion (the matching of the remainder class match(....) recursively).

There is backtracking (if the recursive match doesn't succeed, we try the next token submatch)

#### Sample (*see https://ideone.com/yApYp*)

Only using loops and `std::string` interface (well, and `iostreams` for displaying test output) :)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

typedef std::string::const_iterator It;

/*
 * Extract sequences of non-wildcard characters from pattern range
 */
std::string extract_token(It &s, It e) // [s,e) is (sub)pattern
{
    It wcard;
    for (wcard=s; wcard!=e; ++wcard)
        if ('?' == *wcard) break;

    std::string token(s,wcard);

    for (s=wcard; s!=e; ++s)
        if ('?' != *s) break; // treat '??' as '?' in pattern

    return token;
}

/*
 * Match a (sub)pattern against a (sub)input
 *
 * (See "Strategy" above)
 */
bool match(It patb, It pate, const std::string& input)
{
    while (patb != pate)
    {
        // get next token from pattern, advancing patb
        std::string token = extract_token(patb, pate); // updates patb

        if (!token.empty()) // could happen if pattern begins/ends with redundant '?'
        {
            size_t submatch = input.find(token);  // first submatch please

            while (std::string::npos != submatch)  // while we have a submatch
            {
                if (match(patb, pate, input.substr(token.size())))
                    return true; // match completed successfully

                // look for later potential submatches (*backtrack*)
                submatch = input.find(token, submatch+1);
            }
            return false; // required token not found
        }
    }
    return true; // no (remaining) pattern, always match
}

bool match(const std::string& pattern, const std::string& input)
{
    // just relay to overload more suited for recursion
    return match(pattern.begin(), pattern.end(), input); 
}

//////////////////////
// TEST PROGRAM

void test(const std::string& pattern, const std::string& input)
{
    std::cout << std::boolalpha;
    std::cout << "match(\"" << pattern << "\", \"" << input << "\") => " 
              << match(pattern, input) << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    // matches
    test("?????",               "");
    test("?????",               "?????");
    test("",                    "");
    test("",                    "glorious");
    test("?r?o",                "glorious");
    test("some?words?exist",    "some silly words should, most definitely, be existing");
    test("some??words?exist?",  "some silly words should, most definitely, be existing");

    // failing matches
    test("_",                   "");
    test("_",                   "glorious");
    test("_",                   "glorious");
    test("glorious",            "glo?ious");
    test("?some??words?exist?", "bogus");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but i think @keith.layne is right on this. There are lots of things I didn't understand in that code.

Comment: @keith.layne derp! I'm missing a point somewhere. Using the standard algorithms was 'out' (see OP). However, using string::find surely wasn't? Oh, and backtracking is inevitable due to the nature of the patterns. If you don't want to use recursion you _require_ a stack (e.g. as an array...) and that was also specifically 'out' (see OP)

Comment: @sehe "Clearly, the explanation itself is worth something." I agree. I was originally commenting tongue-in-cheek and I thought you were being pedantic.  Disregard my comments please.

Comment: @keith.layne: Cheers. It's hard to tell these things in comment trails. No harm done :) (comment will selfdestruct in 5 minutes)

Answer (score 2):

Probably you would best create two functions. One to check if a pattern matches a string at some given position, and another one that uses the first function to check all positions in the input string.

The function that checks for a matching pattern would loop over all characters in the pattern, and for each of those characters check if it is either `?` or is identical to the character at the corresponding position in the input string.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps think of the wildcard character as matching every character until you reach the next character or the end of the string. So the algorithm would be:

```
if NextCharToMatch is ? then
  get the next search char
  loop until the input equals the new char to match
```

Comment: You should be backtracking and recursing because if you just 'abort' the `?` match on the next explicit char to match, you'd miss matches like: pattern `?ac` with input of `zzzazzzac` because of the embedded `a` in the input. Or you can work out a different scheme :)

Answer (score 0):

See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12231681/541686), which should also be fast enough for most purposes (it avoids heap allocations as much as possible, and it's basically a nondeterministic finite-state automaton).

Answer (score 0):

*On the past week I started to move my private & public repositories from bitbucket, and I remembered about this.*

The open implementation of C++ wildcards. Native C/C++ & .NET

Now it separated into new project from my sandbox as lightweight, fast and powerful wildcards in addition to slow regex engine etc.

```cpp
enum MetaSymbols
{
    MS_ANY      = _T('*'), // {0, ~}
    MS_SPLIT    = _T('|'), // str1 or str2 or ...
    MS_ONE      = _T('?'), // {0, 1}, ??? - {0, 3}, ...
    MS_BEGIN    = _T('^'), // [str... or [str1... |[str2...
    MS_END      = _T('$'), // ...str] or ...str1]| ...str2]
    MS_MORE     = _T('+'), // {1, ~}
    MS_SINGLE   = _T('#'), // {1}
    MS_ANYSP    = _T('>'), // as [^/]*  //TODO: >\>/ i.e. '>' + {symbol}
};
```

**How to implement own**, etc. Look here:

- https://github.com/3F/regXwild

However, it also possible and for .NET users via [Conari](https://github.com/3F/Conari) engine.

In general, see implementation for 'how it works' or use 'as is' (MIT license)

```cpp
#include "regXwildAPI.h"

using namespace net::r_eg::regXwild;

...
if(searchEssC(_T("regXwild"), _T("reg?wild"), true)) {
    // ...
}
```

```cpp
searchEss(data, _T("^main*is ok$"));
searchEss(data, _T("^new*pro?ection"));
searchEss(data, _T("pro*system"));
searchEss(data, _T("sys###s"));
searchEss(data, _T("new+7+system"));
searchEss(data, _T("some project|open*and*star|system"));
...
```

*Thus, I updated my old answer. Enjoy.*