# c++ Is there a way to find sentences within strings?

Tags: c++, string, pattern-matching

I'm trying to recognise certain phrases within a user defined string but so far have only been able to get a single word.
For example, if I have the sentence:

"What do you think of stack overflow?"

is there a way to search for "What do you" within the string?

I know you can retrieve a single word with the find function but when attempting to get all three it gets stuck and can only search for the first.

Is there a way to search for the whole string in another string?

Comment: please show your code

Comment: to search for a substring in a string, use [std::string::find](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/)

Comment: _"I know you can retrieve a single word with the find"_ Huh?? You can find anything with [`std::string::find()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find). If your problem is varying number of whitespaces in the string, you might need `std::regex`.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, this is a non-trivial question. It requires some knowledge of the language, the grammar, etc. If you're really trying to find `needle` in `haystack`, use `std::string::find` like others have mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use str.find()

```
size_t find (const string& str, size_t pos = 0)
```

Its return value is the starting position of the substring. You can test if the string you are looking for *is contained* in the main string by performing the simple boolean test of returning str::npos:

```
string str = "What do you think of stack overflow?";
if (str.find("What do you") != str::npos) // is contained
```

The second argument can be used to limit your search from certain string position.

The OP question mentions it gets stuck in the attempt to find a three word string. Actually, I believe you are misinterpreting the return value. It happens that the return for the single word search "What" and the string "What do you" have coincidental starting positions, therefore str.find() returns the same. To search for individual words positions, use multiple function calls.

Comment: You were correct, I had been reading the response wrong, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use [regular expressions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>

int main ()
{
  std::string s ("What do you think of stack overflow?");
  std::smatch m;
  std::regex e ("\\bWhat do you think\\b");

  std::cout << "The following matches and submatches were found:" << std::endl;

  while (std::regex_search (s,m,e)) {
    for (auto x:m) std::cout << x << " ";
    std::cout << std::endl;
    s = m.suffix().str();
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Also you can find wildcards implementing with boost (regex in std library was boost::regex library before c++11) [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3300419/file-name-matching-with-wildcard)